# Is type inference broken when a type guard is used in a if statement

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typeguards

Take this code :

```
export type Writable<T> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

class Foo {
    readonly foo = 'foo';
}

class Bar {
    readonly bar = 'bar';
}

type WritableFooBar = Writable<Foo | Bar>;

declare function isFoo(obj: any): obj is Foo;

function test(foobar: WritableFooBar): void {
    if (!isFoo(foobar)) {} // happens also with if(isFoo())

    foobar
    // ^? Foo | Writable<Bar>
}
```

Is type inference broken in this case or am I missing something ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDqUCWMCGAjAG2AB4AVAPjgF44BvAKDibgFopgcATCAOwMTgBtANJxMPOAGtgiCADM4pALoAuRSKUBuegF9t9AMYEcAZxNwAYhAh1Gzdl1784c69TgByVxA-ad9Q2MzOAAhHChbZjgHbj4BPHD3DwSoX10ApBR0LFxCYCsIMIiaDGx8ImICuAAfUPDyfU5gI3DUOQBXHgMYTF4xEwKACgg8ACs1HB5EAEo1EdH%20y2t9Dq6evphgExhB7xS1UtyiAqLZuAA3CExOSOZMBUGAQkwB613rFOnpuh04AHo-nAABY4MAoHjmHAEEw2ADu2CBYjkgxeQy%20ASie3CdiYALgAD0APy6IA)

Comment: This is the expected behaviour – that type guard is only being applied to the code within the if statement, and your trailing `foobar` reference is reached regardless of whether it `isFoo` (or not, as the case may be).

Comment: @motto Just tested the code on different version, it's a regression on TS 4.8 and 4.9. It works fine with the latest nightly.

Comment: my faith in my toolchain has been shaken to the core (plus I misread the question in the first place, think that's enough for me today)

Comment: Versions [`4.7.4`](https://tsplay.dev/WzGREw), [`4.9.5`](https://tsplay.dev/mxjZXw), and [`5.0.1-rc`](https://tsplay.dev/wQ2zAN) all show different inferred types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually a regression that appeared in 4.8 and was fixed in 5.0.